# Save photo to SQLite database and have PHP read it and display it

Tags: php, ios

I want to be able to take a photo with the camera or select one from photos and save it to an SQLite database. I then want to be able to have a PHP server show this image. I tried to convert the image to a string to save it to the SQLite database.

```
// convert image to String.

[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
```

I want to have the PHP server show the image but for some reason it won't work. I think it's because the string is larger than 20 characters. Please help me find a solution.

Comment: Send the actual file rather than a string.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your **php.ini** file and modify following 2 parameters

1. upload_max_filesize
2. post_max_size

See the documentation [here](http://www.php.net//manual/en/ini.php)

or if you haven't access to php ini file try change them with ini_set function.

Answer (score 0):

```
Convert UIImage to NSString:
NSData *dataObj = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
NSString *imgString= [dataObj base64Encoding]; //base 64 string conversion
Store this string to local database. Send this string to PHP server.

In PHP server convert this string to image using base64 encoding.
```